# from c++ development to PHP or Python

Tags: php, python, web

I want to design a website with minimal front end and a backend for periodic processing. Some 200 users will use the site.I have choosen php vs python. I have done few defect fixes in PHP and some automation scription in python and I have absolutely no web development experience. But I have application development experience in c++.

I want to develop the site with ease and minimum effort(no CMS as I want to learn the language). Can anyone suggest me which one choose ?

Comment: *“minimum effort(no CMS).”* Those statements seem somewhat at odds with each other.

Comment: PHP is like a loaded gun. You can do great things with it, but they're not necessarily good. For what it's worth, I have experience with both PHP and Python and I absolutely detest PHP after I got a little experience with something else. For more reasons as to why PHP is bad you could take a look at [this article](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/).

Comment: Go with whatever web language you know best. C++ isn't going to be much use here, but PHP is fine. If you want authentication and so on, a CMS would be useful (e.g. Wordpress), otherwise a framework such as Zend or Symfony.

Comment: I'd ignore that article if I were you @timss - the level of snark in it is one of the things wrong with the software community at the moment. Plenty of spite and not much gratitude, imo. One can do dreadful things in any language, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally think if you have little web development experience you should go with PHP. You can directly embed it in your HTML and perhaps that will make it easier to understand for you. That's of course if you don't want to make complicated websites (yet).

After you familiarise yourself with web development, you can then decide again whether to use PHP or Python depending on the platform you want to use and what you want to achieve.

Moreover if you have C++ experience, PHP's syntax is IMO closer to C++.

Comment: I have academic knowledge about HTML, CSS, Java Servlet and JSP.

Comment: Regardless, I'm sure as a developer you can quickly learn HTML and CSS, and then PHP should fit in nicely in what you've learned.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Wt? http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt c++ web framework.

Python is the better language, but coming from C++ you may find PHP learning curve less steep. PHP language is very C-like.